# How to plus input numbers in HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have the follow code:

I want to do a plus with all inputs, and I'm new in this process, but i try.

```js
var num1 = document.getElementByID('pree');
var num2 = document.getElementByID('pree1');
var num3 = document.getElementByID('pree2');
var num4 = document.getElementByID('pree3');

var result = document.getElementByID('num1 + num2+ num3+ num4');
```

```html
<input type="number" name="pree" value="" id="pree" class="form-control">
<input type="number" name="pree1" value="" id="pree1" class="form-control">
<input type="number" name="pree2" value="" id="pree2" class="form-control">
<input type="number" name="pree3" value="" id="pree3" class="form-control">
<input type="number" name="result" value="" id="result" class="result">
```

I'm really new to this and would like someone to help me with it, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Change your lines like this:
`var num1= +document.getElementByID('pree').value`

Comment: Um, you are not reading the inputs' value. And I have no clue what you are expecting `getElementByID('num1 + num2+ num3+ num4);` to do

Comment: you should first grab the value of those input texts and then add those

Comment: Now is a great time to familiarize yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  Looking at them when you run this code, you will see an error.  That's the first thing for you to investigate.  After that, you can start using the script debugger and/or `console.log` statements to observe specific information about your code, what the values are at runtime, etc.  You can use these tools to *observe* the behavior of your code, rather than otherwise blindly write the code and guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `getElementByID` is a typo. The method is `getElementById` (small "d")
2. Even if you corrected the typo `var result = document.getElementById('num1 + num2+ num3+ num4');` won't do anything because `'num1 + num2+ num3+ num4'` is not the id of any element. You want to assign the total of adding the `values` of those inputs together to the `value` attribute of your result element.
3. You're not checking for any changes on those inputs for you to be able to create the total. [For that you'll need a listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Here's a slightly more modern approach. It uses [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to attach a listener to a containing element to catch `change` events from the inputs as they "bubble up" the DOM. That listener calls the `handleChange` function.

The `handleChange` function resets the total, iterates over all the inputs, and adds their value to the total. Then the value of the `result` is set.

```js
// Cache the elements
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');

// Add a listener to the container
container.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);

// Reset the total, iterate over the input elements,
// and add their value to the total, coercing the string
// to a number first. Finally add that total to the
// value of the `result` element
function handleChange() {
  let total = 0;
  inputs.forEach(input => total += Number(input.value));
  result.value = total;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="number" name="pree">
  <input type="number" name="pree1">
  <input type="number" name="pree2">
  <input type="number" name="pree3">
  <br />
  Result: <input id="result">
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Hello, that answer is perfect, but if i have more inputs type number, the code take literally all the inputs and plus in the result, how i can change that?

Comment: Sorry, forget it, i change only editing in the code the part of "const container & const inputs" i read the documentation you anexed in your answer and i apreciate it, thanks ma men!

Answer (score 2):

I've added a button to control when this fires, but you can change the `name` attribute to the same value on all of them, so that you can retrieve them as an array to loop through:

```js
function addInputs() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('pree');
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      sum += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  var resultInput = document.getElementById('result');
  resultInput.value = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="pree" value="" id="pree" class="form-control">
<input type="number" name="pree" value="" id="pree1" class="form-control">
<input type="number" name="pree" value="" id="pree2" class="form-control">
<input type="number" name="pree" value="" id="pree3" class="form-control">
<input type="number" name="result" value="" id="result" class="result">

<button onclick="addInputs()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you get values from input that would always from type string. if you like to calculate then you have parse to int.

**working example**

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var num1= document.getElementById('pree').value;
  var num2= document.getElementById('pree1').value;
  var num3= document.getElementById('pree2').value;
  var num4= document.getElementById('pree3').value;
  let sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num3) + parseInt(num3) + parseInt(num4)
  document.getElementById("result").value = sum;
  console.log(sum)

})
```

```html
<input  id="pree" value="1">
<input  id="pree1" value="1">
<input  id="pree2" value="1">
<input  id="pree3" value="1">
<br/>
<button>Sum</button>
<br/>
<input  id="result" value="" readonly>
```

Comment: This doesn't reflect changes to the input values.

Comment: @Andy Thank you for your comment! You mean add another event to the calculation? I have added it. Thanks ;-)